# Scripting responses for use in the Maven Release Plugin

Tags: maven-plugin, maven-release-plugin

We are a SVN/Maven/Hudson shop. We are experimenting with using the Maven Release Plugin to help automate our very laborious tagging and releasing process. We are happy with what we are seeing and have researched thus far in regards to this plugin.

Our question is - if we need to have different tags for some of the modules / applications being built, is there a way to script the responses?

We have waded through the interactive dry runs successfully, however we are looking to script these out to further our automation.

Has anyone tried this or know if it is possible?

Does the "Batch Mode" allow this functionality?

Thanks

Joe R

Answer (score 0):

You can -B but it will use default version names (removing -SNAPSHOT at the end).
regarding tags per module you can have a look at the parameter : autoVersionSubmodules [1](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-release-plugin/prepare-mojo.html#autoVersionSubmodules)

/Olivier